# Elementary number theory proofs using functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions

The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined by 
$f(x) =$ remainder when $x^2$ is divided by $7$.

$g(x) =$ remainder when $x^2$ is divided by $5$.

(a) Show that $f(5)=g(3)$

(b) If $n$ is an integer, prove that $f(7n+x)=f(x)$ and state the corresponding result for $g$.

My line of thinking was that $K$ must suppose that there exist a polynomial of highest degree of order $n$ such that when divided by $7$ the remainder will have a term containing $x^2$ but I can't connect my thoughts to the use of $5$.

Answer (score 2):

(a) We have $5^2 = 25 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ and $3^2 = 9 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ So $f(5) = 4 = g(3)$

(b) $f(7n+x) = (x+7n)^2 \pmod{7} = (x^2 + 14nx + 7^2n^2) \pmod{7}$ but since $14nx \equiv 0 \pmod{7} \equiv 7^2n^2$ we have $(x+7n)^2 \pmod{7} =  x^2 \pmod{7}$. Which is just $f(7n+x) = f(x)$.

The corresponding result for $g$ is $g(x + 5n) = g(x)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry I haven't learnt module arithmetic in class but I was asked to try this,  additional information will be greatly appreciated. Thanks